# AVPlayer playerItemDidReachEnd: notification never called (OS X)

Tags: avplayer

I have an AVPlayer object that is playing video fine, however the

```
- (void)playerItemDidReachEnd:(NSNotification *)notification
```

method never gets called.  Not sure what I'm doing wrong as I've followed Apple's documentation exactly.  Here is my code:

```
           self.playerItem = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithAsset:asset];
           [self.playerItem addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"status" options:0 context:&ItemStatusContext];//This works okay
         self.player.actionAtItemEnd = AVPlayerActionAtItemEndNone;
         [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                                  selector:@selector(playerItemDidReachEnd:)
                                                      name:AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification
                                                    object:self.playerItem];
         self.player = [AVPlayer playerWithPlayerItem:self.playerItem];

         self.playerLayer = [AVPlayerLayer playerLayerWithPlayer:self.player];

                        [self.playerLayer setFrame:[[[self playerView] layer] bounds]];
                        self.playerLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill;
                        [self.playerLayer setAutoresizingMask:kCALayerWidthSizable | kCALayerHeightSizable];
                        [self.playerLayer setHidden:NO];
                        [[[self playerView] layer] addSublayer:self.playerLayer];
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code registering the playerItemDidReachEnd: as a callback the last line should be:

```
object:self.player
```

Not the playerItem

Comment: Should be, [self.player currentItem]

Comment: @DavidElliman you're wrong, have you read Apple sample code on AVPlayerDemo ?